# ElasticSearch warning GetIndexRequest accesses system indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using GetIndexRequest with parameter indices = "*".

```
val request = GetIndexRequest()
request.indices("*")
val response = client.indices()[request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT]
```

But I got a warning (migration from ES6 to ES7):

```
this request accesses system indices: [.kibana], but in a future major version, direct access to system indices will be prevented by default
```

GetIndexRequest must show all my indices (it can be without system indices).
 I tried set request type to "open", but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning and only means that in future version (ES 8.x), requesting `*` will not return system indices anymore. So if you don't rely on the current behavior, you're free to ignore this warning.